# OpenGL and CPU/GPU timer synchronization

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to make a CPU and GPU profiler to use in a video game. The goal is to have on-screen 2 graphs that give the time taken by the different tasks of a frame. This is a very crude illustration of what it looks like:

[image]

I'm using QueryPerformanceCounter (on Windows) to get the CPU time and glQueryCounter(GL_TIMESTAMP) to get GPU times.

The problem is that the times I get for CPU and GPU are not relative to the same origin. My first attempt to fix this was to make a blocking call to a GPU timestamp (with glGetInteger64v(GL_TIMESTAMP)) during the initizalization of the app, closely followed by a get of the CPU time. The difference between the two times allowed me to basically convert GPU times to CPU times and have both graphs synchronized. But after a few seconds (or minutes) the times are drifting and my graphs are not correctly synchronized anymore.

I can't make another blocking call to get a GPU time after the game has started because I don't want to loose a frame and make the game stutter.

Did anyone try to do something like this or have any advice on how to synchronize the CPU and GPU times without hurting the performance ?

I have another idea but I don't know if it's going to work well: have a separate thread make the blocking call to get the GPU time, also get the CPU time and send back the difference to the main thread somehow. Then the thread would sleep for a few seconds and start again. I'll try this and update the post if this seem to work well.

**Edit:** I tried the idea above on both an AMD and an NV card and it seems to work fine. Even when calling glGetInteger64v(GL_TIMESTAMP) lots of times (with a sleep of only 1ms between each call), it seems to have no impact on the performance. I still need to make more in depth tests but so far, this looks like a good solution.

Comment: Although I don't have an answer to your question, I would definitely not use the "other idea" method: If you use the same context in both threads, the block will stall the game as if you have used only one thread. When using separate contexts for each thread, the driver will swap out you rendering-context whenever you perform the blocking call, which will also cause stuttering in your game. For completeness: On all GPUs I worked with, the times between gpu and cpu did not diverge that much over time. On my current nvidia 680, it's about a fraction of a millisecond per hour.

Comment: Synchronization... without hurting performance... unlikely IMO

Comment: Another idea: The problem with blocking OpenGL calls is, that they flush your pipeline and wait until this. What about synchronizing directly after swapbuffer, since this already flushes the pipeline? In this case, glGetInteger64v should return immediately

Comment: @BDL What do you mean by "the driver will swap out your rendering-context"? Is a timestamp query considered like a draw call that needs its own command buffer? That seems surprising. In this case, making the query in the main thread and waiting for it to complete in the other thread may work, right? 

For completeness: I tried on a GTX 660 and the times are drifting of about a millisecond every minute (roughly). I also tried on a Radeon HD 7950 and its in the same raneg (but the drifting seems to be in the other direction :o). What method did you use to measure the CPU time?

Comment: I used QueryPerformanceCounter as you did

Comment: @BDL I tried calling glGetInteger64v(GL_TIMESTAMP) after SwapBuffer (and also before). It's working kind of well on Nvidia, it takes around 20us. But on AMD, it jumps between 60 and 200us depending on if the game is GPU bound or not.

Comment: Why do you think `glGetInteger64v(GL_TIMESTAMP)` would be a blocking call? It isn't.

Comment: @derhass Well it's a synchronous API, it returns the value directly. That's what I meant by blocking. By contrast, glQueryCounter + glGetQueryObject is non-blocking if the result is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a separate thread that make a blocking call to glGetInteger64v(GL_TIMESTAMP). It made no visible difference in performance even when waiting something stupidly small like 1ms between each call. Although it should be noted that I already had several OpenGL contexts before this modification.

In the final code, I wait 30 seconds between each call to glGetInteger64v(GL_TIMESTAMP). It seems to be often enough to avoid any visible drifting on all the PCs I tested.

I tested on Nvidia cards (GTX 460, GTX 660, GTX 780ti, GTX 780M) and AMD (Radeon HD 7950), all with Intel CPUs.